# What does debug symbol actually mean on Arch linux for gdb debugging?

Tags: arch-linux, gdb

P.S. English is not my native language; please excuse typing errors.

I've (maybe) understand the basically main idea of *symbol* in ELF file **in dynamic link**.

Refering to textbooks, if I need dynamic link to .so or something like that then I need the link target's function name(Say,If we only talk about the functions). Then the loader do something to find the real location of your target. Then do something else to load it. The function's name is some we can called it a symbol.

But, **in debugging**, the followings confused me.

I tried to install pwndbg(a plugging for GDB) on Arch linux and got some problems. Following these instructions[[1](https://gist.github.com/nbulischeck/bda4397a59b77822703f98f6aeb2cb20)] [[2](https://github.com/pwndbg/pwndbg/issues/340)], I've sovled the problems. But didn't quite understand how did the solution work.

The poster of the solution provider, also the plugging's author said that Arch's glibc doesn't have "debugging symbol" so you need to install it manually, while Ubuntu's glibc has "debugging symbol" -- You don't need to install it manually.

So here comes some question really confused me.

1. Why I can **INSTALL** a symbol for a lib, such as glibc. If a .so (ELF) file didn't have symbol, and you put symbol into it. This will destroy the ELF file fomat, since ELF is based on file relative offset, isn't it? So what did the **INSTALL** actually do? OR what actually "symbol" means in such context?
2. What does `gcc -g`("gcc -g generates debug information to be used by GDB debugger") actually generate? Are they(the thing I installed) same? If I need do "generates debug information" then I must need the source code, is that right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. In a number of distributions ([Debian](https://wiki.debian.org/HowToGetABacktrace), Ubuntu, Fedora, etc.; but not Arch, as far as I can tell from [the corresponding wiki page](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Debugging/Getting_traces)), programs are built with debugging information (see below), but that debugging information is then [*detached* into separate files](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Separate-Debug-Files.html). These separate files are shipped in debug packages and/or through a debug info server, and can be installed alongside the files they help debug.
2. `gcc -g` stores information which essentially allows a debugger to go back from the binary code produced by the compiler, to the source code. Using this information, the debugger can translate a position in the executable or in memory to the corresponding source code: for example, a variable location can be linked to the relevant declaration, and a position in executable code can be linked to the relevant source line.

Michael J. Eager’s [Introduction to the DWARF Debugging Format](http://www.dwarfstd.org/doc/Debugging%20using%20DWARF-2012.pdf) gives a good explanation of the role of debugging information. See also [What is the purpose of /usr/lib/.build-id/ dir?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/411727/86440)