# If I do not care about debug support in red hat packages, what are the drawbacks of turning build-id support off in the specs file?

Tags: rhel, rpm, packaging, rpmbuild, rpm-spec

As a follow up on [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/411736/433212) question, what if I am not interested in having these debug features - how do I simply prevent these build-id files (debug info packages?) from being installed ? Ultimately I do not care (at least for the near future) about supporting debugging at clients. On the other hand, I need to overcome the known "build-id folder conflicts" when installing our different client redhat products (packages) in the same machine. How can that be accomplished ?

1. I [read](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1820370) that using --excludepath=/usr/lib/.build-id/ when installing with rpm is a clean workaround. Sounds so. Do you see any drawbacks except losing "debug capabilities" ?
2. `--excludepath` actually did not help. But using `%define _build_id_links none` as suggested here did. In a short, how problematic is that, if I am not interested in debug support ?
   [enter link description here](https://access.redhat.com/discussions/5045161)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. `--excludepath=/usr/lib/.build-id` is a clean workaround, yes. As far as I’m aware, losing “debug capabilities” *is* the only drawback; files skipped by this option won’t even cause `rpm --verify` to fail. However, losing “debug capabilities” has consequences beyond limiting the ability to get useful output of `gdb`; for example, manual intervention will be required if bug reporting tools want to provide meaningful stacktraces.
2. `%define _build_id_links none` is OK too, if you’re building packages and you don’t want to ship debugging information with them.

Your two questions target different aspects of packages. `rpm --excludepath` affects what happens when a package is *installed*, whereas `%define _build_id_links` affects what happens when a package is *built*. If you’re interested in building packages, it’s normal that `rpm --excludepath` didn’t help, because it’s not relevant then.

Note too that, as suggested by [the bug report you linked to](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1820370), build-id conflicts indicate packaging problems. If you’re building packages, you should fix the issues in your packages, instead of working around them.

Comment: Thanks for the last note. Not much clear to me where the problem is - I have the same machine generating 2 red hat packages, the 2 that when installed on the same machine fails with the conflict mentioned [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/411736/433212). Will look at it in more detail. Both packages have the same parent target directory -> /usr/local/bin - but they ultimately reside in a subfolder there with the package name. What I do not understand is how the same build IDs are generated when packaging different stuff.

Comment: Only now noticed the answer's clarification on the different aspects of my 2 proposed solutions. Thanks a lot for that, very helpful!

Comment: @Stephen what would be the correct approach building rpms with debugging information, making them relocatable and supporting installs on SELinux? Currently, we get `error: lsetfilecon: (/usr/lib/.build-id, system_u:object_r:lib_t:s0) Operation not permitted
error: Plugin selinux: hook fsm_file_prepare failed
error: unpacking of archive failed on file /usr/lib/.build-id: cpio: (error 0x2)` when using `--prefix` during install. `--excludepath=/usr/lib/.build-id` works here too but I like to fix the issue during rpm build.

Comment: @MRalwasser please [ask a new question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) with details of what you’ve tried; you can link to this Q&A to provide context.